# django align right cannot align

Tags: django, alignment, decimal

I'm looking for the simplest way to have aligned right django decimal fields.
Can someone point me to the correct approach?
I have found different post, but it still display aligned left.
Do i have to override the admin, or i miss some simple feature directly in the admin.

I would like to have the 3 columns (ore_dovute, totale, ore_eccedenti), aligned right, with correct formatting for my needs.

```
class TotaliManager(models.Model):
    utente_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=11,null=True)
    ore_dovute = models.DecimalField('ore dovute',max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    totale = models.DecimalField('ore effettuate',max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    ore_eccedenti = models.DecimalField('ore eccedenti',max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Totali per anno / mese"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you talking about the admin list display ?

Comment: Yes!  it is about list display not input.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the admin forms, you will need to override the widget.

[`Widget.attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) allows you to set custom HTML attributes to be added to the form field when rendered. You can override form field widgets in the admin by using [`ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides).

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

from myapp.models import TotaliManager

class TotaliManagerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DecimalField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'text-right'}),
    }

admin.site.register(TotaliManager, TotaliManagerAdmin)
```

In this case, it adds the class `text-right` to the input field. If you use bootstrap, it's built in, otherwise just add the css:

```css
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, you can just add css styles into `attrs` like below.

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.DecimalField: {
        'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'text-align:right;', }),
    },
}
```