# Django: right-align column in admin listview

Tags: django, listview, django-views

How can I output a `DecimalField` right-aligned in Django admin listview? It makes much more sense to have a column of, say, prices, right-aligned.

I tried this: [django align right cannot align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322640/django-align-right-cannot-align), but it doesn't work, presumably, because it doesn't change the *output* behaviour.